# bind the entered text within textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field and a button. when the button is clicked the page is redirected to the same url and I want that the entered field remains binded within the textfield. how can i do that?

**Code**

```
 <input type="text" size="25" style="background-color:#D8D8D8" id="to"/><br><br>  

 <input type="submit" name="scheduleSubmit" value="Submit" id="scheduleSubmit" 
  <button class="btn btn-round btn-success" type="button"></button>
```

**button onclick event**

```
var textBox2 = document.getElementById('to');
value = "?from="+ textBox1.value ;
location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/reports/daily/" + value ;
 document.getElementById("to").value= textBox2.value;
```

Comment: Can you explain better " the entered field remains binded within the textfield"?

Comment: when the button is clicked and redireced, the field goes empty but I want is to display the previous entered text

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the query string with javascript. The query string is stored within the `location.search` object and also includes the `?`.

First, capture the query string as something you can work with:

```
var queryString = location.search.substr(1); // substr(1) will cut off the ? character
```

Then parse the actual string into an object:

```
function parseQuery(str) {
    var result = {}; // going to store the key-value (kvp) pairs in here
    var pairs = str.split('&'); // break it up by the standard ampersand delimiter
    for ( var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++ ) { // go through each of the pairs
        var kvp = pairs[i].split('='); // parse the individual pair using = as the delimiter
        result[kvp[0]] = kvp[1]; // kvp[0] contains the name of the field, kvp[1] contains the value
    }
    return result;
}
var parsedQueryString = parseQuery(queryString);
```

And now populate the form input element:

```
document.getElementById('to').value = parsedQueryString.to||'';
```

Elaborating on the previous line, `parsedQueryString` is now an object (the `result` from from the function return above). The input field is named `to` which corresponds to the key in the query string. We can access it via `parsedQueryString.to`, however, if it was not included in the query string, we want it to fail gracefully (using the or operator `||`) by defaulting to assigning an empty string `''`: `parsedQueryString.to || ''`.

Here is a working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <p><input type="text" size="25" id="to" name="to" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="scheduleSubmit" name="scheduleSubmit" /></p>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function parseQuery(str) {
                var result = {};
                var pairs = str.split('&');
                for ( var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++ ) {
                    var kvp = pairs[i].split('=');
                    result[kvp[0]] = kvp[1];
                }
                return result;
            }
            var queryString = location.search.substr(1);
            var parsedQueryString = parseQuery(queryString);
            document.getElementById('to').value = parsedQueryString.to||'';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the lack of an `action` attribute in the `form` element will just have the browser "post"/"get" the data to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

First of name for your  text field what ever you want.for example, I named the text field as 
**textField**. then check if request is sent from the given textfield;if so, keep the value binded. if not, it will make the value empty. "The code I use"here is PHP so you need server like wampserver in order to see the desired result. otherwise, nothing happens'

```
<input type="text" name = 'textField' value =" if(isset($_REQUEST['textField'])) { echo $_REQUEST['textField'] } else { echo '' } " size="25" style="background-color:#D8D8D8" id="to"/><br><br>
```